# Центрирование текста внутри кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть сайт

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  all__buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
  /*selected__button.click= function(){
        selected__button.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
  };*/
  /*
    function changeColor(inputbutton) {
        inputbutton.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
    
    }
    
  */

  [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button) {
    selected__button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#5f3ec0';
      event.target.style.color = '#ffffff';

    });
  });
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header > .header__text {
position: relative;
width: 93px;
height: 24px;
left: 0;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

font-family: TT Norms;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 100%;
/* identical to box height, or 24px */


color: #000000;
}

/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/


.header__button {
    width: 72px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 2%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="globalcontainer">
        <div class="header">
                <div class="header__text">
                    Обзоры
                </div>
                <div class="header__buttons">
                    <!-- <span> -->
                        <button class="header__button">Все</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Видео</button>               
                        <button class="header__button">Текст</button>               
                        <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
                    <!-- </span> -->
                </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="content">       
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

задает центрирование текста внутри кнопки, но каким образом можно центрировать текст внутри кнопки Краш видео (так чтобы весь текст располагался внутри кнопки в одну строку). Привожу скриншот страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для стиля кнопки добавить `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: да не, просто у кнопки задана фиксированая ширина, лучше паддинги задать, родитель флексом сделать и переносить елементы, если нужно

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header__button {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__buttons">
  <!-- <span> -->
  <button class="header__button">Все</button>
  <button class="header__button">Видео</button>
  <button class="header__button">Текст</button>
  <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
  <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
  <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
  <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
  <!-- </span> -->
</div>
```

Лучше всего сделать это в css.